# Convert LINQ to expression tree

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to dynamically create a LINQ statement including a where statement that has to be extended depending on the items in the pages list:

```
private IQueryable<WS_WebShopTreeNode> GetRootNodes(List<ShopTreePage> pages, IQueryable<WS_WebShopTreeNode> node_src)
{
 var rootNodes = from tn in node_src
                        where tn.id_WebShopTreeNode_AsParent == null &&
                              tn.PageNo == 1 && 
                              tn.PageNo == 2 &&
                              tn.PageNo == 3 &&
                              //etc.
                        select tn;
}
```

`ShopTreePage` is just an enum:

```
public enum ShopTreePage : byte
{
    Unassigned = 0,
    UserRole = 1,
    Hardware = 2,
    Software = 3,
    Zubehoer = 4,
    All = 5
}
```

I know that this can be achieved via expression trees. Unfortunately, I lack of knowledge about building expression trees.

Comment: You havent used `ShopTreePage` or `pages`  in your query so it's hard to understand your question

Comment: You already have an expression tree.  That's what's created when you use lambdas with an `IQueryable`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to tell us which property is a `ShopTreePage` but i guess it's `PageNo`.

Why you can't simply use `Contains` here?

```
var rootNodes = from tn in node_src
                where tn.id_WebShopTreeNode_AsParent == null 
                 && pages.Contains((ShopTreePage)tn.PageNo)
                select tn;
```